# Detect click on a TkTextImage inside TkText

Tags: ruby, events, click, tk-toolkit

I want to bind an event, specifically `Button-1`, to a `TkTextImage` which is placed inside a `TkText`. However, the event never fires. I have tried other events such as `Enter` and `Leave` and these aren't fired either.

The image is displayed correctly, but it just doesn't fire any events.

I am using the following code:

```
root = TkRoot.new(title: 'Hello, world!')

img = TkPhotoImage.new(file: 'test.gif')
text = TkText.new(root)
text.pack

text_image = TkTextImage.new(text, '0.0', image: img)
text_image.bind("Button-1", proc do
  puts "Image click!"
end)

puts "Running app..."
Tk.mainloop
```

How can I enable my `text_image` to detect events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a direct solution.
How about using TkTextWindow and TkButton?

```
require 'tk'

src = TkScrollbar.new.pack(side: :right, fill: :y)
text = TkText.new.pack(side: :left, fill: :both, expand: true)
text.yscrollbar src

img = TkPhotoImage.new(file: 'test.gif')

button= TkButton.new(image: img) do
  relief :flat
  command {puts "Image click!"}
end

TkTextWindow.new(text, '0.0').window=button

Tk.mainloop
```